# Install Mysql-worbench without the client

Tags: 14.04, dpkg, mysql-workbench

Hi i want to install workbench so i am doing

```
sudo apt-get install mysql-workbench
But this the outcome

    The following extra packages will be installed:
  libdbd-mysql-perl libdbi-perl libgtkmm-2.4-1c2a libmysqlclient18
  libnet-daemon-perl libplrpc-perl libterm-readkey-perl libtinyxml2.6.2
  libzip2 mysql-client mysql-client-5.5 mysql-client-core-5.5 mysql-common
  mysql-workbench-data python-all python-mysql.connector python-pysqlite2
  python-support
Suggested packages:
  python-pysqlite2-doc python-pysqlite2-dbg
Recommended packages:
  mysql-utilities
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libdbd-mysql-perl libdbi-perl libgtkmm-2.4-1c2a libmysqlclient18
  libnet-daemon-perl libplrpc-perl libterm-readkey-perl libtinyxml2.6.2
  libzip2 mysql-client mysql-client-5.5 mysql-client-core-5.5 mysql-common
  mysql-workbench mysql-workbench-data python-all python-mysql.connector
  python-pysqlite2 python-support
```

But i already have a mysql client and i dont wan't to install this new one.
i tried to download the deb and here is the control file

```
Depends: libatkmm-1.6-1 (>= 2.22.1), libc6 (>= 2.14), libcairo2 (>= 1.13.0~20140204), libcairomm-1.0-1 (>= 1.6.4), libctemplate2, libcurl3 (>= 7.16.2), libexpat1 (>= 2.0.1), libgcc1 (>= 1:4.1.1), libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0 (>= 2.22.0), libgeos-c1 (>= 3.4.2), libgif4 (>= 4.1.4), libgl1-mesa-glx | libgl1, libglib2.0-0 (>= 2.35.9), libglibmm-2.4-1c2a (>= 2.36.2), libgnome-keyring0 (>= 2.22.2), libgtk2.0-0 (>= 2.24.0), libgtkmm-2.4-1c2a (>= 1:2.24.0), libhdf4-0-alt, libhdf5-7, libjasper1, libjpeg8 (>= 8c), libmysqlclient18 (>= 5.5.24+dfsg-1), libncurses5 (>= 5.5-5~), libnetcdfc7, libodbc1 (>= 2.2.11) | unixodbc (>= 2.2.11), libpango-1.0-0 (>= 1.18.0), libpangocairo-1.0-0 (>= 1.14.0), libpangomm-1.4-1 (>= 2.27.1), libpcre3, libpcrecpp0 (>= 7.7), libpng12-0 (>= 1.2.13-4), libpq5, libpython2.7 (>= 2.7), libsigc++-2.0-0c2a (>= 2.0.2), libsqlite3-0 (>= 3.6.0), libstdc++6 (>= 4.6), libtinyxml2.6.2, libuuid1 (>= 2.16), libx11-6, libxerces-c3.1, libxml2 (>= 2.7.4), libzip2 (>= 0.10), odbcinst1debian2 (>= 2.2.11-3), zlib1g (>= 1:1.2.0)
```

Is the libmysqlclient the actual mysql client ? 
Anyway i tried to install this by dpkg but theres a lot of missing or outdated dependencies. So first of all why is it trying to install another mysql client if i already have one ? (i have MYSQL_HOME set and contactanated to PATH) ? If i have to install manually all the missing packages with dpkg. i know that i can do in one command, but about the packages that are already there but outdated ?

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$ sudo apt-get download mysql-workbench
Get:1 http://id.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/universe mysql-workbench amd64 6.0.8+dfsg-2 [7.449 kB]
Fetched 7.449 kB in 5s (1.409 kB/s)          
$ dpkg --force-all -i mysql-workbench_6.0.8+dfsg-2_amd64.deb
```

1. `sudo apt-get download mysql-workbench`
2. `dpkg --force-all -i FILENAME.deb`

edit:

For upgrade use this command: `sudo apt-get install mysql-workbench --only-upgrade`